# Can pom.xml be set up to run testNG(UI perf. tests) tests and jUnit(unit tests) tests separately, from command line?

Tags: maven, junit, testng

The process requires tests to be performed on a branch before a pull request can be approved. Since testNG is used for UI Selenium tests and jUnit for unit tests, `pom.xml` plugins had to be set like this:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

UI tests are run with test xml suite which has to be defined somewhere in pom.xml(not sure where to put that line). Can `pom.xml` be set up so tests can be done separately? e.g. `mvn -DsuiteXmlFile=/path/to/file` and `mvn -Dtest=package.with.unit.tests'

Comment: Have answered the question, let me know if that helps

Comment: Two different profiles solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You need to make two separate testng files with different names and add unit tests in one testng and performance tests in other and you can parameterised it from the pom.xml like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: "[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>." This is the console output.

Comment: Yes so when you are running the mvn clean install you need to add suitexmlfile as well. For example: `mvn clean install -DsuiteXmlFile="testng.xml"`

Comment: yeah, but there are other errors. i cannot copy everything